# Concatenate 3d and 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I have 2 arrays

The first one has this shape

```
(4133,10000,12)
```

and the second one has this shape:

```
(4133,2)
```

I want to combine those two arrays so I get this shape

```
(4133,10000,12,2)
```

Comment: Please check out the answer and edit your question accordingly. I would be happy to assist you with it. Thank you.

Comment: No, you don't want to do this.

Comment: Make two small sample arrays and show exactly what you want the result to look like.  Or show you intend to use the result for.  Other than a matching first dimension there's little reason to join these.

Answer (score 0):

Shape of an array along a dimension is NOT the total number of elements. It is the number of elements ***PER*** corresponding dimension. Thus, you cannot concatenate arrays of shapes `(4133,10000,12)` and `(4133,2)` to have an array of shape `(4133,10000,12,2)`. An easier example to think of is two matrices of shapes `(m,n)` and `(m,k)`. You cannot concatenate them to have an array of shape `(m,n,k)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by *combine* but you can reshape the arrays then let broadcasting kick in.  For example:

```
x = np.empty((10,8,4))
y = np.empty((10,2))
combined = x.reshape((10,8,4,1))*y.reshape((10,1,1,2))
print(combined.shape)
# (10,8,4,2)
```

Comment: This solution multiplies the two arrays (by broadcasting). I don't think that is what OP has in mind.